# Execution order of operator new and argument of constructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, order-of-execution

Does C++ spec specify the order `operator new` and the constructor of `A` in `new C(A())`.
The g++ let the order be `A()` -> `new` -> `C()`, but clang++ let it be `new` -> `A()` -> `C()`.
Is the difference caused by unspecified behavior?

g++    :7.4.0
clang++:10.0.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "call A()\n";
    }
};

struct C {
    C(A) {
        std::cout << "call S()\n";
    }

    void *operator new(size_t s) {
        std::cout << "call new()\n";
        return malloc(s);
    }
};

int main() {
    void *p = new C(A());
}
```

Comment: Are you building as C++17, C++14 or prior?

Comment: Two notes: You tagged this with "C", which clearly shows you didn't read that tag's description. Don't. Now, you ask about "undefined behaviour" (UB). This is a term used by the C++ standard to mark things where anything can happen and which should be avoided. There is also "unspecified behaviour", which is probably closer to what you're after, because the code is technically fine and doesn't cause UB.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt Thank your suggestion. I mixed up the two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clang is correct. Since C++17 the execution order is guaranteed. [[expr.new]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#19)

> The invocation of the allocation function is sequenced before the evaluations of expressions in the [***new-initializer***](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#nt:new-initializer).

`operator new` (the allocation function) is supposed to be invoked firstly, then the evaluation of expression in the new-initializer (i.e. `A()`).

Before C++17, the order is not guaranteed. [[expr.new]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.new#18) (C++14)

> The invocation of the allocation function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the evaluations of expressions in the [***new-initializer***](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.new#nt:new-initializer).

---

<sup>It seems gcc isn't conforming to C++17 (and later); compiling with [gcc10 in C++2a mode](https://wandbox.org/permlink/STst15OX7AaZWoTy) gives the same result.</sup>